# How can I specify multiple users and passwords in Ansible vault file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I have created hosts:

```
sudo cat /etc/ansible/hosts
[Prospectorium]
192.168.1.50
[Scholarium]
192.168.1.60
[Bulwark]
192.168.1.70
```

And a playbook that should update those servers:

```
sudo cat /home/overlord/ansible/apt.yml
- hosts: all   become: yes   tasks:
  - name: Update and upgrade apt packages.
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
      upgrade: full
      autoremove: yes
      autoclean: yes
      cache_valid_time: 43200
```

Each of those 3 hosts has a different username and password:

```
prospectorium
prospectorium123

scholarium
scholarium123

bulwark
bulwark123
```

So now my question:
How can I securely pass login information when I run a playbook?

I tried creating a vault file, but that can contain only one password and no username, so that is not applicable to me.

Answer (score 4):

There are more options. You might want to try the *host_vars* and *group_vars* first.

---

1. host_vars

It seems the symbolic names are the names of the hosts rather than the names of the groups. See [Inventory basics: formats, hosts, and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups). In this case, the inventory file might be

```ini
shell> cat hosts
Prospectorium ansible_host=192.168.1.50 ansible_user=prospectorium
Scholarium ansible_host=192.168.1.60 ansible_user=scholarium
Bulwark ansible_host=192.168.1.70 ansible_user=bulwark
```

Put the passwords into the *host_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/Prospectorium.yml 
ansible_password: prospectorium123
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/Bulwark.yml 
ansible_password: bulwark123
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/Scholarium.yml 
ansible_password: scholarium123
```

Test it

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i hosts --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    ungrouped:
      hosts:
        Bulwark:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.70
          ansible_password: bulwark123
          ansible_user: bulwark
        Prospectorium:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.50
          ansible_password: prospectorium123
          ansible_user: prospectorium
        Scholarium:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.60
          ansible_password: scholarium123
          ansible_user: scholarium
```

Encrypt the passwords if this is what you want to.  See details in [Encrypting content with Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#encrypting-content-with-ansible-vault)

```bash
shell> ansible-vault encrypt host_vars/Prospectorium.yml 
Encryption successful
```

```bash
shell> ansible-vault encrypt host_vars/Scholarium.yml
Encryption successful
```

```bash
shell> ansible-vault encrypt host_vars/Bulwark.yml
Encryption successful
```

You can see that the files were encrypted and the *ansible-inventory* command shows the same result.

```bash
shell> cat host_vars/Prospectorium.yml 
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
64316362396261663735333239653163366630313463636262393735356139376536346665383334
3865663166623862363832326231363362666263643536390a396239373737363133313332623539
...
```

Test the structure in a playbook. For example, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          ansible_user: {{ ansible_user }}
          ansible_password: {{ ansible_password }}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [Prospectorium] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_user: prospectorium
    ansible_password: prospectorium123
ok: [Scholarium] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_user: scholarium
    ansible_password: scholarium123
ok: [Bulwark] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_user: bulwark
    ansible_password: bulwark123

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
Bulwark                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
Prospectorium              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
Scholarium                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You can add other variables into the encrypted files in *host_vars* if you want to.

---

2. group_vars

An elegant option is putting the data into the *group_vars/all.yml*. For example

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml
passwords:
  Bulwark: bulwark123
  Prospectorium: prospectorium123
  Scholarium: scholarium123

users:
  Bulwark: bulwark
  Prospectorium: prospectorium
  Scholarium: scholarium

ansible_password: "{{ passwords[inventory_hostname] }}"
ansible_user: "{{ users[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

Encrypt *group_vars/all.yml*

```bash
shell> ansible-vault encrypt group_vars/all.yml
Encryption successful
```

Remove the *host_vars* and users from *hosts*

```bash
shell> cat hosts
Prospectorium ansible_host=192.168.1.50
Scholarium ansible_host=192.168.1.60
Bulwark ansible_host=192.168.1.70
```

The same playbook gives the same result

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************
ok: [Prospectorium] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_user: prospectorium
    ansible_password: prospectorium123
ok: [Scholarium] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_user: scholarium
    ansible_password: scholarium123
ok: [Bulwark] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_user: bulwark
    ansible_password: bulwark123

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************
Bulwark                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
Prospectorium              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
Scholarium                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

3. vars

You can put the variables into any file you want to and include them in a playbook. For example, remove all the *host_vars* and *group_vars* from the previous examples and put the file into the directory *vars*

```yaml
shell> cat vars/ansible_ssh_vars.yml
passwords:
  Bulwark: bulwark123
  Prospectorium: prospectorium123
  Scholarium: scholarium123

users:
  Bulwark: bulwark
  Prospectorium: prospectorium
  Scholarium: scholarium

ansible_password: "{{ passwords[inventory_hostname] }}"
ansible_user: "{{ users[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

Encrypt the file

```bash
shell> ansible-vault encrypt vars/ansible_ssh_vars.yml 
Encryption successful
```

Include the file in a playbook. For example, the playbook below gives the same result

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - vars/ansible_ssh_vars.yml
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          ansible_user: {{ ansible_user }}
          ansible_password: {{ ansible_password }}
```

Comment: Thank you, everything works perfectly and as it should except when trying to put it inside my playbook. I will try to find a solution to that.

Comment: I added an example of how to put the variables into any file and include it in a playbook. There is no silver bullet. It's up to you how you store the data. See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).